# Connected $G_\delta$ non-singleton, proper subsets in a connected complete metric space with more than one point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is a question related to my last; I have still not solved it. Maybe this one is easier:

Suppose $X$ is a connected complete metric space with more than one point. Must $X$ contain a non-singleton non-empty connected $G_\delta$ proper subset?

Comment: A component from $X-\{x\}$ would probably work. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then $X$ is a so-called continuum (compact connected metric space). And it is well-known that any non-degenerate (non-singleton) continuum has infinitely many proper non-degenerate subcontinua.

Comment: If $X$ is compact, then $X$ is a so-called continuum (compact connected metric space). And it is well-known that any non-degenerate (non-singleton) continuum has infinitely many proper non-degenerate subcontinua. So the interesting question concerns the non-compact case. So the above question could be answered in the affirmative if any connected complete metric space had a non-empty non-singleton compact connected subset. (Recall: For any $G_\delta$ subset $Y$ of $X$ the subspace $(Y,\tau_Y)$ of $X$ on $Y$ is complete. And any closed and thus compact subspace of a complete space is complete.)